# Animated/Video Background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a project that have an Activity with Video/Animated Background and 4 Button

i like design this Activity like TuneIn Radio App's Login Page.

Thanks for Helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use new [Property Animation Api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for color animation:

```
 Integer colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
Integer colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
 colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
    textView.setBackgroundColor((Integer)animator.getAnimatedValue());
}

});
 colorAnimation.start();
```